# .NET Core 2.1 OData v4 modify $filter on server side

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata

I need to modify the `$filter` on the server-side of .NET core 2.1 API.  I have looked at these:

https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/33660648/odata-v4-modify--filter-on-server-side

[OData V4 modify $filter on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660648/odata-v4-modify-filter-on-server-side)

[The best way to modify a WebAPI OData QueryOptions.Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440644/the-best-way-to-modify-a-webapi-odata-queryoptions-filter)

(and a couple of others)

They all do something along the lines of:

```
//Get the URL
var url = queryOptions.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
//Then modify the URL
url = url.Replace("$filter=ID%20eq%201", "$filter=ID%20eq%202");
//Apply the URL
return queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable);
```

The problem being is that it appears in .NET core there is no `RequestUri`.  I am able to get the query multiple different ways:

```
var query = originalRequest.QueryString.Value;
//or a foreach loop
var filter = Request.Query;
foreach (var x in filter)
//...
```

However both `QueryString.Value` `Request.Query` gives me an error "Value has no setters"

Also the method `ApplyTo` is not in .NET Core.

What is the correct way of doing this in .NET Core?  Is there some package that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Xaphann You could extend `EnableQueryAttribute` in the manner below:

```
public class ExtendedEnableQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        // ... second check in the if statement might be overkill - abundance of caution?
        if (queryOptions.Filter != null && queryOptions.Request.Query.ContainsKey("$filter"))
        {
            var stringValuesDict = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();

            foreach(var kvPair in queryOptions.Request.Query.Where(d => !d.Key.Equals("$filter")))
            {
                // This way the new StringValues instances are owned exclusively by substitute query collection
                var values = new List<string>();
                foreach(var value in kvPair.Value)
                {
                    values.Add(value);
                }
                stringValuesDict.Add(kvPair.Key, new StringValues(values.ToArray()));
            }
            // Substitute the $filter option
            stringValuesDict.Add("$filter", new StringValues("ID eq 202"));
            // Substitute the request query collection
            queryOptions.Request.Query = new QueryCollection(stringValuesDict);

            queryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryOptions.Context, queryOptions.Request);
        }

        return base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions);
    }
}
```

You can then proceed to apply this extended attribute to your controller action.
I tested it practically and it seemed to work for an expression like this:

`?$filter=ID eq 201&$orderby=Name&$select=Name`

If this approach works for you, my advise would be to test more extensively and maybe also write a few tests to validate the behaviour